# video and audio do not play in youtube, or any other video streaming as well as VLC and Windows Media player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-playback

Seems like my computer caught some kind of a disease. when you reboot the computer, it will behave just fine. You cannot detect it at the first chance. but give it some time and gradually it can no longer pretend that it is fine.

So I start my computer, and feel like watching a video on youtube, or just watch a film with VLC. it's just working fine and seems like there's no problem.
Now, in case of Youtube (or any other sites where I can watch streaming video), after it playes like five or more minutes, if I ever put it on pause for a minute and then I again start playing it, 2 things might happen:
a. either it may freeze at that frame and not play on
b. or it would play on but not with the audio.

at times after clicking to a video, the page goes on loading, the blue thing at the top goes on round and round, and all the I see is white. and at times the page loads, but not the video. I mean that there's no such buffering going on, but the video box is just black. I have an okay internet speed like 625 kbps, so no internet connection problem can happen. it sometimes tell me that the shockwave plugin isn't working. so every time it forces me to click the "stop plugins" button.
I've tried installing the latest adobe players both shockwave and flash, disabling and enabling again. But nothing worked

[Note that these problems happen not only on Chrome but on other browsers like Firefox or Internet explorer.]

In case of VLC or Windows Media Player, the manifestations are a bit different.
If I open a file (mp4, mkv or anything) it might open or might not, just randomly. if the session has just started, it might open, or if the session is not so young, like 10 or 15 mins. past then it might not open.
a. If it opens and at one point I pause it and then when I again start it, the frame freezes.
b. sometimes, after clicking it, it wouldn't open. But when I check the Task Manager, it says that the VLC is running. and if I click on to End Task, and again try to open an mp4 or mkv file, then it wouldn't play past it's first frame.

I'v tried doing Tools>Preferences>Reset Preferences.
And, Tools>Preferences>Video>Display...Output> change from Automatic to Directx (DirectDraw) Video Output.
I've also tried reinstalling windows.
to get rid of this problem temporarily I always have to reboot, but then problem starts again. I don't know if I could ever get rid f it. Please help me solve this. My specs:

*windows 8.1

*Intel Core i3  - 2105 @3.10GHz

*RAM 4GB, 3.70 usable

*64bit

Please help me solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try disabling hardware decoding in VLC ? Preferences -> Input/Codecs -> Hardware-accelerated decoding

Comment: I remember trying that too,but didn't work. Thank you, Ely, for cooperating :)

Comment: sounds like some graphics card/window creation issue.  Is your computer plugged into multiple monitors?  Does it happen in safe mode? What if you swap out the graphics card? :)

Comment: rogerdpack, No extra graphics. it's inbuilt. Only one montor